# How do I open a txt file and call method? [C++]

Tags: user-interface, c++-cli

I just started C++, and I need a little help. What I have is an existing cmd prompt interface which I have to create a gui for.

I need to store data from a .txt file into an array. The file is opened in a File Browser and the user selects it. How do I make the make it so that the method is called?

Here's my button code:

```
private: System::Void btnVenue_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

OpenFileDialog ^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog();<
openFileDialog1->Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a Venue File";

if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
    System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew<br>
    System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
    // MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadToEnd());
    sr->Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my LoadVenueData which loads the data from the text file.

```
void CLoader::loadVenueData(string filename)
{
    string line;
    int examIndex = 0;

    ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {       
        // Read venue data
        for (int i = 0; i < numSessions; ++i)
        {
            int number;
            myfile >> number;
            sessions[i].setCapacity(number);
        }
            myfile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Cannot open venue file: " << filename;
};
```

Comment: The `^` annotation for (managed?) pointers is not standard C++. I would recommend coding in C++11.

Comment: This is not (plain) C++. Looks like C++/CLI

Answer (score 1):

To create a `std::string` from `System::String` you can use the `marshal_as` libraries from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

The code would look something like

```
obj.loadVenueData(msclr::interop::marshal_as<string>(openFileDialog1->FileName);
```

If possible, a wide alternative may be favoured here (see the comments on file name characters etc.)

```
obj.loadVenueData(msclr::interop::marshal_as<wstring>(openFileDialog1->FileName);
```

Comment: At the price of not being able to open files whose name contains any non-`Windows-1252` characters. The best solution would be keeping the filename in wide-character strings from end to end.

Comment: @Medinoc. True, I agree. That constraint is from the original system. It may not be viable to convert from narrow to wide. I always advocate the usage of wide from the start of a project for a Windows Application, for this very reason (or the `_T()` type techniques, in one or another variation, when both may be required). I'll update the answer to reflect the wide alternative.